# Why does my apps icon disappear after an ad hoc install (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios4, adhoc

I have an app that I'm trying to install via standard OTA ad hoc. On iOS 4.1 The app installs ok. On newer versions (4.3.1 and 4.3.3 tested) the app installs without error, but the icon disappears from Springboard when the install is done. If I restart the device the icon is back.

I have two questions:

- Does anyone know what causes this behaviour?
- Is this a problem when it comes to App
  Store submission?

Edit: It's the whole icon that disappears, not just the graphics. It is not possible to start the app from Springboard.

Comment: In my case a restart of the device did the trick...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this question is similar to this one:

[In-House App Disappears After Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606833/in-house-app-disappears-after-install)

Give it a try, maybe it helps...

Answer (score 3):

Just spent hours sorting out the same problem.

We deliver our **AdHoc** build over-the-air.

**Turns out that when I changed app ID, I didn't change the bundle-identifier parameter in the OTA installation plist**.

Comment: so how did you do it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that both high and standard resolution icon files are entered correctly into the info.plist file.

On older versions of iOS, entering just the standard resolution file name for the "Icon File" Key was sufficient, iOS would select the high resolution file by just adding @2x to the filename.
On newer versions there is the "Icon Files" (note the plural form) Array, where you may enter several files in different resolutions. I experienced similar errors using the "old" style, which were resolved using the new one.

Comment: I have both "Icon File" and "Icon Files" in my info.plist. Just to be thorough I removed "Icon File" from the plist file and tested again, but that did not work.

Comment: Hmm... concerning your edit..: you mean theres NOTHING? No blank (white) icon, you can see the homescreen background where the icon is supposed to be?

Comment: Nothing at all, no icon, no text, just the background. It shows a gray icon during installation (with the blue progress bar), but as soon as the installation finishes it disappears.

Comment: That's odd. Really odd! Never heard of such a case before - and my answer obviously won't help you. Maybe your icon file is corrupt in some way? Wrong color mode / profile, wrong resolution, contains transparency, is an interlaced png...? This is just a random shot, though. I'm sorry I don't have any better ideas for you at this point...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the problem was that our distribution/provisioning certificates had all expired in between when the ipa was created and when it was installed on the device. Renewing all the certificates, rebuilding and redeploying fixed the problem.