# App Installed from IPA distribution/development provisioning profile disappears after install

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, xcode7.3, ios9.3

I'm working on a Unity Project that is to be built on iOS platform. I have a testing device iPad 3rd Gen and iPad mini 4 (both running on iOS 9.3.1), which builds and run for both devices (either xcode build or IPA install).

What I want to do is send the IPA exported from xcode 7.3 to the internet and let the our coworkers test the App.

Notes:

- I have their UDIDs added to our developer account
- I've made separate Distribution and Development provisioning profile IPAs
- All devices are installed to each provisioning profiles
- And uses same App ID
- Includes In-App purchase

I don't have any problem with running and building it using excode. But the issue starts when I send the IPA to them and test them to an iPad mini 4 and iPhone 6.

**What happens is that the app finishes installation then after installation the app disappears.**

I found some similar thread like this "[In-House App Disappears After Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606833/in-house-app-disappears-after-install][1])" Followed the solutions but still doesn't work, the issue still happens.